# Is there an assembler available for Mac OS 7.5.2?

Tags: assembly

Following my last quesiton ([Is there a compiler available for Mac OS 7.5.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514706/is-there-a-compiler-available-for-mac-os-7-5-2)), I'm wondering if there is an assembler that I can *download* for Mac OS 7.5.2? I'm not particularly interested in finding an IDE, but I may need a suitable text editor. Also, it would be nice if the program could fit on a 1.4MB floppy disk (since I'm struggling to find a way to network my old PowerBook).

Comment: Oh my goodness, the *memories*...

Comment: This assumes that *two* floppy disk drives could be found that still work. Tall assumption.

Comment: Hans, actually that was very easy. USB FDDs are very cheap and still available, and the FDD in the PowerBook works just fine. Not a very tall assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking for a System 6 assembler myself. The closest thing I've come across is [Fantasm/LIDE](http://www.afturgurluk.org/mirrors/macintosh/www.lightsoft.co.uk_Fantasm/fant.html) which should run on System 7.1. I found one of the downloads ([LIDE3Dec2002.sit](http://files.sys5.se/LIDE3Dec2002.sit)), but as it is just 6.61 MB,  it may not be complete.

Comment: Good answer still, I think I will struggle to find something under 1.4MB.